# Support multiple cmake minimum versions for one project

Tags: cmake

I have a fairly popular open source project that has a minimum cmake version set that is fairly old (~Oct 2013).

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)`

This is great for supporting a wide variety of users, but it makes adding new things to our cmake builds challenging, since we cannot use any of the new features in later cmake versions. This leads to complicated cmake files and more maintenance burden to emulate future improvements made to cmake.

I would like to support two `CMakeLists.txt` files for the project that have different minimum versions, one legacy one at the `2.8.12` version, and another more modern one at a later `3.x` version. Is there any canonical way to do this? It doesn't look like there is a way to support multiple `CMakeFiles.txt` at the root of the project.

The naive way is to just rename the legacy file `CMakeFiles_Legacy.txt` and have users that depend on the older cmakes manually switch out the `CMakeFiles.txt` on their own.

Comment: The project's `CMakeLists.txt` could check CMake version via variable [CMAKE_VERSION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VERSION.html) and according to checks use either "old" or "new" implementation.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do that to an extent, to add new things that don't have any old implementation possible. The problem with this is the `CMakeLists.txt` becomes littered with conditionals and creates more maintenance burden. I wish to keep them separated in distinct files so I don't have conditionals to worry about.

Comment: The only way to avoid conditionals based on CMake version is to write the code which works both for newer and older versions. "I wish to keep them separated in distinct files so I don't have conditionals to worry about." - You could check the version in the main `CMakeLists.txt` and, depending on the version include either `CMakeLists_legacy.txt` or `CMakeLists_new.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: **Just don't support old versions.**

CMake is absurdly easy to upgrade. Literally every halfway-modern development platform natively packages at least CMake 3.16+, but Windows and macOS are both way ahead of the curve with constant updates to the included version.

Visual Studio receives periodic updates and 2022 includes CMake 3.21. The version on Chocolatey is always up to date.

On macOS the Homebrew version is always up to date.

On Debian derivatives, Kitware provides an official APT repo that is always up to date. There is also a Snap package that is always up to date.

On most other Linux distros, one can use the [official binaries](https://cmake.org/download/) directly from Kitware without `sudo` access at all. They have x86_64 and aarch64 binaries. The binaries  are statically linked and require only libc6 as a dependency. Glibc has been ABI-stable since 1997. **It will work on your system.** But even if it doesn't, building a recent CMake version isn't difficult anyway. Your users maintaining such archaic systems shouldn't be your liability.

(aside: I wrote an entire blog post on this... https://alexreinking.com/blog/how-to-use-cmake-without-the-agonizing-pain-part-1.html)

Comment: Thanks for your blog post, especially the table of versions. However, we are still supporting old tools like VS2013, Windows 7, and pre C++1z compilers, so I don't want to break those users who have really old tools. Of course, I wish all users are keeping up their tools, and cmake is pretty easy to upgrade.

Comment: @Moop - CMake 3.22 still supports Visual Studio as old as VS6 and AFAIK Kitware's MSIs will install on Windows 7, even though all of those tools are well past EOL. I'd wager it will be an order of magnitude more work to set up a multi-version CMake build (which will have to be continuously tested in those old environments) than to help the few stragglers update a single build tool.

Comment: CMake 3.14 dropped support for Windows XP and Vista, but Windows 7 is still supported today.

Comment: @AlexReinking is this cited somewhere in the CMake docs?

Comment: @jpr42 - yes: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.14.html#deprecated-and-removed-features -- "Support for running CMake on Windows XP and Windows Vista has been dropped. The precompiled Windows binaries provided on cmake.org now require Windows 7 or higher."